# Formula to extract certain character positions in a string

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I'm busy here with excel but kind of struggling with some kinda formula.
I got first and last name in one cell and I want to combine them in an another cell. but I just want the first letter of the first name and the first 5 letters of the last name.
because both are in one cell I don't really know how to do it. Also I'll have to deal with the space in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, this can be done using [concatenate](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/CONCATENATE-function-8f8ae884-2ca8-4f7a-b093-75d702bea31d), [left](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LEFT-LEFTB-functions-9203d2d2-7960-479b-84c6-1ea52b99640c) and [mid](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MID-MIDB-functions-d5f9e25c-d7d6-472e-b568-4ecb12433028)

```
=CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1,1),MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,5))
```

This assumes there's **only one space** in the name - immediately before the last name.

You might also want to use this one, depending on how complex your cells are

```
=CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1,1),RIGHT(A1,IF(LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1)>4,5,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1))))
```

Comment: Excellent! If this solves your problem, be sure to click the green check mark next to the answer to mark the question as solved, that way anyone looking will see there's a sufficient solution.